# Complex Event Processing-Esper

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I wonder if there is any information (e.g. a diagramm) on how the components of Esper source code collaborate in order to produce the query results.For example,when a select query is applied,the data is stored in an array and where does that happen in Esper's source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structures depend on the query. Lets say you have a "select * from MyEvent" that means there is no data structure that anything gets stored in. But instead if you have "select * from MyEvent.win:time(1 min)" there is a 1-minute window of events that one can iterate over using iterator API and that the engine does keep 1 minute of events in a data structure. For the time window the data structure is probably closer to a list. There any many different queries possible with all sorts of data windows and patterns and subqueries and more. All these are not one data structure but different ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @cory